# How many points can you find on $y=x^2$, for $x \geq 0$, such that each pair of points has rational distance?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, rational-numbers, open-problem

Open problem in Geometry/Number Theory.  The real question here is:

*Is there an infinite family of points on $y=x^2$, for $x \geq 0$, such that the distance between each pair is rational?*

The question of "if not infinite, then how many?" follows if there exists no infinite family of points that satisfies the hypothesis.

We have that there exists a (in fact, infinitely many) three point families that satisfy the hypothesis by the following lemma and proof.

**Lemma 1:**  *There are infinitely many rational distance sets of three points on $y=x^2$.*

The following proof is by Nate Dean.

*Proof.*  Let $S$ be the set of points on the parabola $y = x^2$ and let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two fixed rational values.  For any point, $P_0(r)=(r, r^2) \in S$, let $C_1(r)$ be the circle of radius $d_1$ centered at $P_0(r)$ and let $C_2(r)$ be the circle of radius $d_2$ centered at $P_0(r)$.  Each of these circles must intersect $S$ in at least one point. Let $P_1(r)$ be any point in $C_1(r) \cap S$ and likewise, let $P_2(r)$ be any point in $C_2(r) \cap S$.  Now let $dist(r)$ equal the distance between $P_1(r)$ and $P_2(r)$. The function $dist(r)$ is a continuous function of $r$ and hence there are infinitely many values of $r$ such that $P_0(r)$, $P_1(r)$,
and $P_2(r)$ are at rational distance. $ \blacksquare $

This basically shows that the collection of families of three points that have pairwise rational distance on the parabola is dense in $S$.

Garikai Campbell has shown that there are infinitely many nonconcyclic rational distance sets of four points on $y = x^2$ in the following paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-248/S0025-5718-03-01606-5/S0025-5718-03-01606-5.pdf

However, to my knowledge, no one has come forward with 5 point solutions, nor has it been proven that 5 point solutions even exist.

But I know that many people have not seen this problem!  Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach a proof of either the infinite case or even just a 5 point solution case?

**Edit:**  The above Lemma as well as the paper by Garikai Campbell do **not** include the half-parabola ($x \geq 0$) restriction.  However, I thought that the techniques that he employed could be analogous to techniques that we could use to make progress on the half-parabola version of the problem.

Comment: Any insights/strategies/useful theorems that may be used to make some progress are welcome in the comments, since I know that people seldom submit an answer that they don't consider complete.

Comment: You add $x\geq0$ in the problem,but it's not appear in *Lemma 1*,and the paper you refered did not say $x\geq0$,do you need this condition when you try to find a five-point solution?

Comment: Ah yes, I apologize, the problem is supposed to be restricted to the half-parabola, so $x \geq 0$ should be included.  The paper that I was referencing was only exploring the four point solutions that are nonconcyclic, but I don't think that he included the restriction of $x \geq 0$ in any of his arguments, I should have looked at the paper more thoroughly.  However, I think that some of his techniques may still apply in exploring this problem further, even with restricting it to the half-parabola.  Thank you for the correction, I'll add that right now and +1 to you for catching that.

Comment: You have to show that $dist(r)$ is not an irrational constant...

Comment: The idea of Nate Dean's proof was two fix two circles with rational radii $d_1$ and $d_2$ at one point, and since these circles will intersect the parabola at at least one point each, this generates our three points, with $d_1$ being the distance between $P_0(r)$ and $P_1(r)$; $d_2$ being the distance between $P_0(r)$ and $P_2(r)$, each being rational.  Since $dist(r)$ is continuous, and since the rationals are dense in the reals, we can shift the three points up and down the parabola, keeping $d_1$, $d_2$ constant and letting $dist(r)$ vary, yielding an infinite number of rational values.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the logic of this proof?  The only part that I could see being questionable is that the density of the rationals in the reals implies that there are an infinite number of rational values for $dist(r)$, since we're dealing with, if we let $P_1(r) = (r_1,r^2_1)$ and $P_2(r) = (r_2,r^2_2)$, the solution to $dist(r) = \sqrt{(r^2_2 - r^2_1)^2 + (r_2 - r_1)^2}$, which I believe still maintains the density of the rational solutions in the whole solution set, I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: The Campbell paper does have an example of a 5-point rational distance set on $y=x^2$, but from the context it appears four of the points lie on a circle. $x=0,\pm91/60,\pm209/120$.

Comment: The nonconcyclic/non-negative constraint sure does make this problem interesting.  I wonder what techniques would need to be used to explore the 5-tuple and up range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the "infinite family" question appears to be, no. Jozsef Solymosi and Frank de Zeeuw, On a question of Erdős and Ulam, Discrete Comput. Geom. 43 (2010), no. 2, 393–401, MR2579704 (2011e:52024), prove (according to the review by Liping Yuan) that no irreducible algebraic curve other than a line or a circle contains an infinite rational set.

Comment: Thank you!  I just found the arXiv PDF, here it is if anyone else wants to take a gander: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.3095v2.pdf